# jquery select box selection default option

Tags: jquery

i have a select box and i want to select the first option,below is the html and the jquery code

```
<select class="t_type">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="1">App1</option>
</select>
```

Lets say i have APP1 selected now..Which i want to change the option back to select..How to do this

```
$(".t_type option:first").attr('selected','selected');
        or
$(".t_type").prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

`EDIT`

I need to select optionv val="-1" and not APP1.I have tried all the answers below before and it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".t_type option:first").attr('selected','selected');
        or
$(".t_type").prop('selectedIndex',true);
```

reference [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  and [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".t_type option:first").attr('selected','selected');
```

or

```
$(".t_type option:first").attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('.t_type option:first').prop("selected", true);
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9WeK/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this below demo:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/zqLa9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".t_type option:first").attr('selected','selected');
});
```